# Finding the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

How does one find the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix? I am using Cramer's rule to solve a system of linear equations but don't know how to find the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix. Our matrix is with variables and not actual values so the answer will be in terms of the variables. Is there a rule/formula that I can use to get the determinant without using co-factor expansion?

The matrix given is

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 &-6 & 8 \\
0 & 7 & 3 & 0 \\
-1 & 8 & 7 & -4 
\end{bmatrix}

, but then to use cramers rule and then to find the subsequent determinants the matrix will change? so was hoping for a general formula?

Comment: Laplace expansion and Gaussian elimination are two rather general methods which can be used. But "the way to go" can also depend on the structure of the matrix you are given. If, say, for example it is a block matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}$, then its determinant is $\det(A)\det(C)$. So you should probably include the matrix in your question.

Comment: Oliver has some good advice which highlights the difficulty of answering your question. Evaluating a general 4x4 determinant is rather tedious (you'd need to use an expansion along some row or column). If you could post the matrix you're actually dealing with, you might get better advice (there may be a short cut which applies to that particular matrix).

Comment: Most codes will compute the determinant by first decomposing the matrix, i.e. using a (pivoted) LU decomposition. Of course, once you have an LU decomposition, you can solve your linear system without needing any determinants, which is why Cramer's rule is infrequently used for numerical computation.

Comment: Can you please select and answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

When using Cramer's rule, there will be *no* variables whatsoever, rather, you know that the coordinates of the solution to $Ax=b$ are given by $$x_i=\frac{\det{(A\mid i)}}{\det A}$$ where $(A|i)$ is the matrix obtained by replacing $A$'s $i-th$ column with the column vector $b$. I give you an example on how to compute $\det A$, and maybe you can compute the remaining determinants yourself. Recall how how the detereminant behaves:

$({\rm i})$ It remains unchanged if we sum a multiple of a row (column) to another row (column)

$(\rm ii)$ It changes sign if we permute two rows (columns)

$(\rm iii)$ Scalars hop off the determinant.

Thus you may partially triagulate your matrix and operate as follows 
$$\begin{align}
  \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   1 & 1 & { - 2} & 3  \\ 
   0 & { - 2} & 0 & { - 1}  \\ 
   0 & 7 & 3 & 0  \\ 
   0 & 9 & 5 & { - 1}  \\ 
 \end{matrix} } \right) &=  - \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   1 & 1 & { - 2} & 3  \\ 
   0 & 2 & 0 & 1  \\ 
   0 & 7 & 3 & 0  \\ 
   0 & 9 & 5 & { - 1}  \\ 
\end{matrix} } \right) \cr 
  \text{cofactor} &=  - \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   2 & 0 & 1  \\ 
   7 & 3 & 0  \\ 
   9 & 5 & { - 1}  \\ 
 \end{matrix} } \right) \cr 
    R_2-3R_1\to R_2'\;,R_3-9R'_2\to R_3'\;\;  &=  - \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   0 & { - 6} & 7  \\ 
   1 & 3 & { - 3}  \\ 
   0 & { - 22} & {26}  \\ 
 \end{matrix} } \right) \cr 
  \text{ permute rows } &= \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   1 & 3 & { - 3}  \\ 
   0 & { - 6} & 7  \\ 
   0 & { - 22} & {26}  \\ 
 \end{matrix} } \right) \cr 
  \text{ cofactor } &= \det \left( {\begin{matrix}
   { - 6} & 7  \\ 
   { - 22} & {26}  \\ 
 \end{matrix} } \right) =  - 2 \end{align} $$

You can also triangulate it, and just calculate $\prod a_{ii}$ which is almost what I did above. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=calculate+determinant&f1=%7B%7B1%2C1%2C-2%2C3%7D%2C%7B3%2C1%2C-6%2C8%7D%2C%7B0%2C7%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C8%2C7%2C-4%7D%7D&f=Determinant.detmatrix_%7B%7B1%2C1%2C-2%2C3%7D%2C%7B3%2C1%2C-6%2C8%7D%2C%7B0%2C7%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C8%2C7%2C-4%7D%7D) is W|A's computation.

---

**ADD** There is a formula that does not involve cofactors, but it involves $4!=24$ terms, namely $$\det A=\sum_{\sigma \in S_4}\operatorname{sgn}\sigma a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$$

Answer (score 1):

A "quick" method to compute the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix by hand, is by using cofactor expansion.

Let $ D =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 &-6 & 8 \\
0 & 7 & 3 & 0 \\
-1 & 8 & 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix}$

Here we are going to choose which row/column contains the most $0$'s Clearly, row 3 contains the most. So we will exand along that row.

Start with the first term in row three, which is $0$ and multiply it to the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ sub-matrix $M$, which you can obtain by covering up the column and rows that intersect at the term. Which should look like this:

$0 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -2 & 3 \\
 1 &-6 & 8 \\
 8 & 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix}$

As you can see, we can obtain a $3 \times 3$ matrix containing all original entries of our $4 \times 4$ matrix, excluding those from column 1 and row 2.

Now, we repeat this process for the remain terms in row three: $7,3,0$:

$\text{det}(D) =$

$ 0 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -2 & 3 \\
 1 &-6 & 8 \\
 8 & 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix} $
$- 7 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & -2 & 3 \\
3  &-6 & 8 \\ 
-1 & 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix} +$
$ 3 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1  & 3 \\
3 & 1  & 8 \\
-1 & 8  & -4 
\end{pmatrix} - $
$0 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2  \\
3 & 1 &-6 \\
-1 & 8 & 7  
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrices being mutliplied by $0$ can be discarded. So we are left with:

$\text{det}(D) = - 7 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & -2 & 3 \\
3  &-6 & 8 \\ 
-1 & 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix}+$
$ 3 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1  & 3 \\
3 & 1  & 8 \\
-1 & 8  & -4 
\end{pmatrix}$

Expanding along row 1 in both resulting $3 \times 3$ matrices and we get:

$\text{det}(D) =$

$ -7 \cdot \{\begin{pmatrix}
-6 & 8 \\ 
 7 & -4 
\end{pmatrix} + $
$2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
3  & 8 \\ 
-1 & -4 
\end{pmatrix} + $
$3 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
3 &-6  \\
 8 & 7 
\end{pmatrix}\} + $

$
3 \cdot \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 8 \\
 8  & -4 
\end{pmatrix} - $
$\begin{pmatrix}
3  & 8 \\
-1   & -4 
\end{pmatrix} + $
$ 3 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1  \\
-1 & 8   
\end{pmatrix}\}$

Now all you have left is to comupute six $2 \times 2$ matrices.

As far as computing this with variables, the same principles of cofactor expansion can be applied. Just determine which row/column contains the most $0$'s (if any) and expand along that row.

Comment: For the second round of expansion, I would have expanded along the second column of each matrix, so that there are only three $2\times 2$ determinants instead of six.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.